# Wordpress-Menu always running into xampp localhost

Tags: wordpress

I have two sites and I was already placed both of the sites into my hosting/hosting services. But when I needed to edit the template and made some changes I always downloaded into my pc and using my xampp as localhost.

After finished copying into my localhost and changed the live url into local url I ran the sites and worked perfectly fine, but when I was clicked all the menu it running into my xampp localhost.

I've tried to edit the pages, categories for my menu still it didn't worked, then I tried again creating new page or category for my menu, but still the same, when I clicked the menu always opened or running into my xampp localhost.

Any idea why?I've already make changes the site url into my localhost.

Thank you.

Best regards,

Kris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refresh your .htaccess file by setting

```
Settings -> Permalinks
```

on your live site. See more info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_.htaccess_file)

Comment: Thank you so much...I almost installing new wordpress for my old site. Thank you.... :)